# ASP.NET Web API CORS works fine in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox

Tags: firefox, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've set up a REST api with ASP.NET Web API and enabled CORS like so:

```
<system.webServer>
 <httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

The jQuery ajax call works in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox I get a `NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed`.

Do Firefox have some especially tough restrictions when the site is `http://localhost`? Have I missed something in my Web.Config that FF needs?

Thanks!

**## Edit:**

It look like it's the OPTION method that does not work.
The OPTION method is not allowed in Chrome either but Chrome goes ahead making the GET request anyway. Firefox gives 405 for the OPTION and then never makes the GET.

This is the request from chrome dev tools:

[image: chrome dev tools]

Comment: Could you share how the raw request looks like from FF? and also how the request looks like from Chrome/Safari where its working..

Answer (score 1):

Try using fix domain instead of "*" solved the problem in our case
`<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add following line under system.web -> handlers in web.config?

<remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />

This default handler may block your option request

Comment: It had no effect, but it sounds pretty reasonable that some handler/module/whatever is handling the OPTIONS. I found ppl with similar problems discussing the WebDAV module (eg. https://gist.github.com/eugeneagafonov/4338381)

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same situation. The options-keyword rose a 405 HTTP Error. Well, the solution was to switch from IISExpress (Development Application Server) to ISS 7.x. There are (of course) significant restrictions using a development web-server. This solved the issue you mentioned for me.